# Is there some way to get amsul pickadate/pickatime object in the different script after picker initializing and use on('close') event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, pickadate

There is amsul pickadate plugin on my project.
Can I get pickadate/pickatime object in the different script to use on handler? (I don't want to change core js script, where is pickadate initialization).

I tried to do that:

```
$('input[data-type="date"]').on('close',function(){
                        // do something
                    });
```

also I tried to do:

```
$('input[data-type="date"]').pickadate('picker').on('close',function(){
                        // do something
                    });
```

But on both ways it didn't work at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you missing one `.pickadate()` chain. It should be :

```
$('input[data-type="date"]').pickadate().pickadate('picker').on('close',
    function(){
      //Do something here
    }
);
```

Here is working example at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jPjLnERt4WeMVbTYvaiN?p=preview) show how to bind `close` event using `on`.

Please check detail API documentation at: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with pickadate 3.5.6 version.

Inspect your date picker input id and use it below.

```
$('#input-id').pickadate('picker').on({
  close: function() {
    //Do something here
  }
});
```